# I don't understand why my nodejs/javascript regex isn't working

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have some simple text I'm trying to parse:

```
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 346 Mar  1 08:50 save_1
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Feb 28 17:28 save_2
-rw-rw-r-- 1   0 Feb 28 17:28 save_3
```

And I have a regular expression that I have tested working on different regex testing websites:

```
\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\w{4}\_\d
```

I'm trying to take the sample text as an input in the following function in a Node.js application and return an object or array with the 3 different matches, from the month to the end of the line.

```
function parse(str) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\w{4}\_\d");
    return regex.test(str);
    //return str.match(regex);
}
```

I don't understand why the boolean from .test() is false and the object from .match() is null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Also: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to return 3 strings, each starting with the month, and ending at the end of the line.

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to achieve. I don't think you want to return a string. You want to get information about a folder, right?

Comment: @TimWolla: Right.  I know that this folder will have 3 and only 3 files.  I'm trying to get the names and date/time of last access from them.  I figured I could just split the strings once I have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse the output of `ls`, [which is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you should simply use file system operation provided by node.js. Using file system operations you can be sure your program will work in (almost) any edge case as the output is well defined. It will even work in case the folder will contain more or less files than three in the future!

As you stated in the comments that you want the names and date / time of the files from a folder. So let us have a look at:

[`fs.readdir(path, callback)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback): `fs.readdir` will give you an array of filenames in the folder specified in path. You can pass them to `fs.stat` to find out the mtime:

[`fs.stat(path, callback)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fstat_fd_callback): `fs.stat()` will give you an object of [`fs.Stats`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) which contains the mtime in the `mtime` property.

So your code will look something like this afterwards:

```
fs.readdir('dir', function (err, files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var filename = files[i]
            fs.stat('dir/' + filename, function (err, stats) {
                console.log(filename + " was last changed on " + stats.mtime);
            });
        })();
    }
});
```

The output is:

```
[timwolla@~/test]node test.js
5 was last changed on Fri Mar 01 2013 20:24:35 GMT+0100 (CET)
4 was last changed on Fri Mar 01 2013 20:24:34 GMT+0100 (CET)
2 was last changed on Fri Mar 01 2013 20:24:33 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

In case you need a return value use the respective `Sync`-versions of these methods. These, however, will block your node.js eventing loop.

Comment: This seems the wiser approach!

Comment: fs.readdir() is working like a charm, but for some reason, I get this error with fs.stat(): { [Error: ENOENT, stat 'save_1'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'save_1' }

Comment: @bbbgscott fs.readdir only seems to give the filenames. Prepend the directory manually then: `fs.stat('my/directory/' + files[i]...`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is failing as you need to escape the `\` when passing a string to the RegExp constructor, i.e. `\s` should be `\\s`.

```
var regex = new RegExp( "\\w{3}\\s+\\d{1,2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\w{4}_\\d", "g" );
```

The `g` flag is added to get all the matches.